# Mysql Database not updating through the cms I have made?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Right, I hope this is the last problem on this particular project - 
Its a personal diary project, the code in the index page echoes the menu bar with all the days, a div for the post and a div that contains a slider of images.

I have two databases, one is pages and the other is images they both have column called "pageorder" that helps me specify which images go to which page.

Now these images have a title and description, it all works!

The next part is the interface, I have made a page to CRUD the pages and to CRUD the images, the pages one works perfectly fine and CRUDs the database entries. However the images one will not update even though the echo message displays "Databse updated" without giving me errors so I think there is something wrong in my code.

```
<?php 

include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

$pid = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "/[^a-z]/", $_POST['pid']); // filter everything but numbers for security

$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE pageorder='$pid' ORDER BY id ASC"; 
$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error());
$imageedit = ''; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $id = $row["id"]; 
    $images = $row["images"];
    $title = $row["title"];
    $desc = $row["description"];
    $pageorder = $row["pageorder"];

    $imageedit .= "<table width='300'>
    <tr>$id</tr>
    <tr><img src='$images' width='204' height='153' /></tr>
    <tr><textarea name='title' id='title' cols='30' rows='1'>$title</textarea></tr>
    <tr><textarea name='description' id='description' cols='60' rows='1'>$desc</textarea></tr>
    <tr>$pageorder</tr> </table>";
} 
mysql_free_result($query); 
?>
```

and the form details

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="administrator/page_images_parse.php"  onsubmit="return validate_form ( );">
<?php print $imageedit ?>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit Page Edit" />
<input name="pid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pid; ?>" />
  </form>
```

When I go to my edit_index.php page that will ask me what page I want to edit, I tell it the number e.g. 1 and it will grab all the images associated with page 1. There are 18 images on page one when I update any title or description data it will not go into the database.

So I think there is a problem in the "page_images_parse.php"

The Code:

```
<?php

include_once "../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";


$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$desc = $_POST['description'];


$query = mysql_query("UPDATE images SET title='$title', description='$desc' WHERE pageorder='$pid'") or die (mysql_error());

echo 'Operation Completed Successfully! <br /><br /><a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
exit();
?>
```

I think there is a problem with the WHERE pageorder='$pid' function, but I have tried various things but nothing seems to be working.

P.S. I know about php injection but don't need it for this project as it is offline, personal and no one else will see it!

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: it won't update the images database through the edit page I have made. The pages one works perfectly fine.

Comment: how can you edit multiple images in one go as the while loop contains same name and id for all rows. eg: description,title

Comment: I thought about this, does this mean, I cannot update multiple images or the code is wrong for this action? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: is there any primary key fro the records in the table? it seems $pid is same for all images in a page.

Comment: After the query, try outputting the return value of `mysql_error()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:

```
$pid = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "/[^a-z]/", $_POST['pid']);
```

you can use

```
 $pid = (int) $_POST['pid'];
```

also filter the data against mysql injection

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE pageorder='".mysql_real_escape_string($pid)."' ORDER BY id ASC") or die (mysql_error());
```

**EDIT:**

update the while loop as:

```
 $i=0;
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     $id = $row["id"]; 
     $images = $row["images"];
     $title = $row["title"];
     $desc = $row["description"];
     $pageorder = $row["pageorder"];

     $imageedit .= "<table width='300'>
     <tr>$id</tr>
     <tr><img src='$images' width='204' height='153' /></tr>
     <tr><textarea name='title[".$i."]' id='title[".$i."]' cols='30' rows='1'>$title</textarea></tr>
     <tr><textarea name='description[".$i."]' id='description[".$i."]' cols='60' rows='1'>$desc</textarea></tr>
     <tr>$pageorder</tr>
    <input type='hidden' name='id[".$i."]' value='".$id."' />
    </table>";
    $i++;
 }
```

and page_images_parse.php as

```
 foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $id)
 {
    $pid = $id;
    $title = $_POST['title'][$key];
    $desc = $_POST['description'][$key];
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE images SET title='$title', description='$desc' WHERE id='$pid'") or die (mysql_error());
 }
```

Comment: nope! Did not work. All the images have a unique ID and also have a pageorder, the first page has 18 images, all with pageorder 1 which corresponds with the pid. 

So how would I word that in the {"UPDATE images SET title='$title', description='$desc' WHERE pageorder='$pid'"}

Comment: are you expecting multiple rows with this? while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { code in yours

Comment: I want to update multiple rows in the database, for example, page one has 18 images - all with title and description.

Comment: is there any primary key for the records in the table? it seems $pid is same for all images in a page.

Comment: yes there is a primary id, the $pid will be same for all images as that is how I have set it so that the collection of images echoe out on the right page. The common factor here being page order.

Comment: i have edited the answer. its untested .. but may give you an idea.

Comment: I will try this later and let you know how I get along, but the code seems to be a little clearer and makes more sense now.

Comment: I have tried your code and now what is happening it is updating all the fields in the database but with same entry. I put in individual entries for the title and description for all the images, but what happens is that it updates all the entries with the same details. 

Also it is giving me an error of Uninitialized string offset on $pid = $_POST['pid'][$key];

Comment: I sorted out the problem, your code worked the only change I made was to add a second clause in the UPDATE line - WHERE id='$id' AND pageorder='$pid'